# Solr 6.3 how to speedup dataimport

Tags: solr

The max speed I got when import data is 6 docs per second. Is there any way to speed up dataimport by changing configuration files?

UPD:

1. I am export from mySql. Total number of records from all tables ~2.5 million; ~4.5 Gb of data
2. Hardware: 8 core processor, 4 Gig RAM
3. Combine document (~50 fields) from 21 SQL tables.

Comment: Please edit your question including the following info: a)what are you importing from?(mysql,sql,text file, etc...) b) what is the hardware of the machine importer c) example of document imported

Comment: @AR1, please see updated question. Is there anything else you need.

Comment: Have you increased solr JVM settings?

Comment: How long does it take to just export the result set from the same MySQL-query through the regular `mysql` console? (i.e. is the slowness from indexing or from fetching?)

Comment: @Oyeme yes, I set it to 12 Gb (-Xmx12g), but actually it uses not more than 2GB

Comment: @MatsLindh not sure how to measure it. I have ~20 tables - which one to check? what would be a good result of fetching?

Comment: @MatsLindh try to check one by one.

Comment: Are you using multiple queries in separate `entity` blocks? Or one single, large query?